# Is there some way where I can get the data from a useSelector and store it as an initial value of a useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Let's say I have this useSelector:

```
const mapState = ({ data }) => ({
  Items: data.items,
});
```

And the items is an array. This is in JSON object:

```
[
  {
    itemName: "Item1",
    itemPrice: "5",
  },
  {
    itemName: "Item2",
    itemPrice: "5",
  },
];
```

These are the codes:

```
 const Item = () => {
      const { items } = useSelector(mapState);
      const dispatch = useDispatch();  
  

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getData(Items));
  }, []);
    
  //store a data item.name inside the useState
  const [itemName, setItemName] = useState("");

  return (
    <Container>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

Is it possible to set the initial value of the itemName from a data of useSelector? Like something like this?

```
const [itemName, setItemName] = useState(itemName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not read the code, but simply provide the value of the data from useSelector and feed in to the component as props.

Use that props as the initial value of useState.

Simple code, simple to understand

Comment: Even if the values in the useSelector is an array?

Comment: Well, it should rather be object for convenience, but my answer is still the same for array